# Unable to setup Kubernetes Ingress for QuestDB via Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, questdb

I'm a beginner to Kubernetes, Helm and Yaml. I'm trying to access the QuestDB Console via Kubernetes Ingress Controller setup in my minikube, but i'm getting the below error when running a helm upgrade. Could anyone advice how I can correct this?

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to create resource: Ingress.extensions "questdb" is invalid: spec: Invalid value: []networking.IngressRule(nil): either `defaultBackend` or `rules` must be specified
```

Here's my overriding value.yaml

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  rules:
    - host: localhost
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /questdb
            backend:
              serviceName: questdb-headless
              servicePort: 9000
          - path: /influxdb
            backend:
              serviceName: questdb-headless
              servicePort: 9009
```

I've installed the QuestDB helm chart using a local version which has only slightly modified the original ingress.yaml to reference networking.k8s.io/v1 instead of networking.k8s.io/v1beta1. Here's what it is locally:

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "questdb.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.14-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
{{- else -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "questdb.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
        {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
          {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

I'm running on these versions:

```
- helm : v3.6.0
- Kubernetes : 
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409edcfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:23:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.2", GitCommit:"faecb196815e248d3ecfb03c680a4507229c2a56", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:20:00Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

NAME                    NAMESPACE       CHART                           APP VERSION
kubernetes-ingress      default         kubernetes-ingress-1.15.2       1.6.2
questdb                 default         questdb-0.8.0                   6.0.3
```

More details on the original chart and templates can be found here: https://github.com/questdb/questdb-kubernetes/tree/master/charts/questdb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ingress template expects things to stay under `.Values.ingress.hosts` but in your values are under `.Values.ingress.rules`.

Additionally, paths needs to stay directly under hosts items, not under http, because the ingress is using it with a

```
{{- range .paths }}
```

under `.Values.ingress.hosts` items. And, paths are just strings, as the service name and port are directly taken from the `fullname` and the `.Values.service.port`

---

I would try changing your values to something like:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - host: localhost
      paths:
        - "/questdb"
        - "/influxdb"
```

or something close to this.

Additionally, you can try and see what is the output of an helm upgrade or install command if you add the parameters `--debug --dry-run` which could greatly help you identify problems like those, showing the definitions as they will be created (if there's no error while building the template, of course)

---

**Update**: since you also changed the Ingress template to use `networking.k8s.io/v1`, you need to also change how the template is created, because the new kind of Ingress expects things in a different way, as you can see in the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Rules could becomes something like this:

```
rules:
{{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
- host: {{ .host | quote }}
  http:
    paths:
      {{- range .paths }}
      - path: {{ .path }}
        backend:
          service:
            name: {{ .svc }}
            port:
              number: {{ .port }}
      {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and remove the declarations of

```
{{- $fullName := include "questdb.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
```

which are now useless. With this, you can change your values in the following:

```
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
    - host: localhost
      paths:
        - path: "/questdb"
          svc: questdb-headless
          port: 9000
        - path: "/influxdb"
          svc: questdb-headless
          port: 9009
```

But the service taht you specify in the values must be created somehwere of course (by the ingress and it needs to expose the desired ports)

Comment: I tried the --debug --dry-run options and it seems to complain it can't find the serviceName and servicePort. How should I specify them in overriding values.yaml?

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: [ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown field "serviceName" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend, ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend): unknown field "servicePort" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressBackend,

Comment: This is because you changed the definition to use networking.k8s.io/v1 but you didn't change the template. The new Ingress resource definition expects things at different paths and in a different way. I'll modify my answer to explain

Comment: thanks, I had to add an additional "pathType : {{ .pathType }}" to ingress.yaml, followed by adding "pathType: Prefix" to values.yaml, and then I was able to install the helm chart successfully